# How can run a schedular and cache certain list of data and use Cacheable over a request handler method?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cache, spring-scheduled

Say I have a spring-boot web application, Now, I want a scheduler to run every night calling an external service fetching a data set say in json format, which I will be mapping into java model class.

I need to use spring cache service to cache this data.
So that when I deploy my web application , user's can click an icon on the UI, which will call my controller say `getData(HttpServletRequest req)` api and  I retrieve all the data that I have cached.

Again when the scheduler executes I will `cacheEvict` all the data and store the data afresh.

```
/*
when user click the ui icon this endpoint should get invoked, and 
the already cached data should be returned
*/
@GetMapping("/data")
public Student getData() {
 Student student= studentService.getStudents();
}

/*
Running schedular and fetching data.
*/

@Scheduled(initialDelayString = "DELAY", fixedRateString = 
"RATE")
public void callExternalService() 
{
  this.callExternalServiceAndGetData();

}
```

Comment: You haven't actually defined what is your problem.

Comment: My problem is how can I cache the response coming from the schedular so that when user requests those data I can deliver from the cache. So when user makes such a request the call goes to a particular controller and then into a particular service class and into a method and from there it should fetch the data that was earlier collected by the cache. How can I obtain this?

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html? Also https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial is worth reading.